# append element to subsist when condition matched

Tags: python

```
Group = [['car','truck'],['car','trusthost1 10.10.30.1','trusthost2 10.10.40.1','truck'],[car,trusthost1 10.10.30.1,trusthost2 10.10.50.1,truck,]['car','truck'],['car','trusthost1 10.10.35.1','trusthost2 10.10.44.1','truck']]
for i in Group:
    for k in i:
        if re.search('trusthost',str(k)):
            i.append(k)
```

my above code is not working

every time when element include "trusthost" it should add after last element of sublist

expected result:

```
Group = [['car','truck'],['car','truck''trusthost1 10.10.30.1','trusthost2 10.10.40.1',],['car','truck','trusthost1 10.10.30.1','trusthost2 10.10.50.1']['car','truck'],['car','truck','trusthost1 10.10.35.1','trusthost2 10.10.44.1',]]
```

Comment: Do not call your variables `list`, `dict`, `tuple` or the like.

Comment: I'm afraid you must make it clearer what you want to do before we can help you...

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "every time when element include "trusthost" it should add after last element of sublist"? I'm having a hard time understanding this sentence. Also, do you actually want to modify the existing nested list, or is creating a new list fine as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
Group = [['car', 'truck'], ['car', 'trusthost1 10.10.30.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.40.1', 'truck'],
     ['car', 'trusthost1 10.10.30.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.50.1', 'truck'], ['car', 'truck'],
     ['car', 'trusthost1 10.10.35.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.44.1', 'truck']]
for lst in Group:
  st = []
  lst1 = []

  for elem in lst:
    if elem.startswith('trusthost'):
        st.append(elem)
    else:
        lst1.append(elem)
  lst1 += st
  lst.clear()
  for i in lst1:
    lst.append(i)

print(Group)
```

This yields:

```
[['car', 'truck'], ['car', 'truck', 'trusthost1 10.10.30.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.40.1'], ['car', 'truck', 'trusthost1 10.10.30.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.50.1'], ['car', 'truck'], ['car', 'truck', 'trusthost1 10.10.35.1', 'trusthost2 10.10.44.1']]
```

Hope this will help you.